# What do the symbols on a tire mean?

Tags: tire

What do the symbols on tires mean for example
kenda nevegal 
(54-559) 
k1010-009  
1113513C   
/\ / 167  (/\ / symbol of two triangles)
NYLON 
I want to find out when my tires should be replaced.
Thanks.

Comment: We have a bunch of questions on when to replace tires. The short answer is, when they're worn and you're getting flats, or something has happened to damage the integrity of the tire. As for teh markings you mean, taking a picture would be helpful

Comment: Are you asking what the symbols mean or are you asking when to replace the tire? They are two separate questions.

Comment: thnak you yes , i want to know the life time and when i must replace them

Comment: Tyres don't have a "use by" or "replace by" date.  A lot comes down to storage.  If they're cracked to the point you can see the cloth through the cracks, its time to replace them

Answer (score 3):

- "kenda nevegal"  is the brand and model of tyre
- 54-559 is the width of the tyre (about 2.1 inches) and diameter of the bead (a 26" MTB tyre)

The other numbers are useless to you.

Curiously, none of those numbers say anything about tyre pressures.

Comment: thank u , i use a pressor about 45 psi (min 40- max 65) because of that i want to check the life time of the tire

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace tires when they are worn out. Depending on the type of tyre, there are a number of signs to look for:

- Tread that was there, is no longer there (may not apply to road tyres)
- Sidewall cracks/starts to show through
- Keep getting punctures- this is because the remaining surface is so thin.